# Are there stenography benefits to a "n-prime"?

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, prime-numbers, certificates, safe-prime

As mentioned in this [StackOverflow CodeGolf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/148999/2460), prime numbers can be redefined:

> One of my favorite definitions of the prime numbers goes as follows:
>
> - 2 is the smallest prime.
> - Numbers larger than 2 are prime if they are
>     not divisible by a smaller prime.
>
> However this definition seems
>   arbitrary, why 2? Why not some other number? Well lets try some other
>   numbers will define n-prime such that
>
> - n is the smallest n-prime.
> - Numbers larger than n are n-prime if they
>     are not divisible by a smaller n-prime.

based on this notion, and we find a union of "real primes" and this fictional subset:

- Are there any cryptographic algorithms, stenography approaches that can be adapted to use an `n-prime`?
- If I look at the case of `n-prime == 2`, I assume that there are computation and size efficiencies vs other values for `n-prime`. What other benefits does `n-prime == 2` offer?
- Similarly how the primes `3` and `65537` provide cryptographic benefits as RSA exponents, are there other worthwhile values for `n-prime`?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70392/discussion-on-question-by-lamontecristo-are-there-stenography-benefits-to-a-n-p).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but I think this definition of “n-prime” number is just nonsense.

Mathematicians defined prime numbers the way they did, because it provides a set of numbers with interesting mathematical properties. A simple example is that any positive integer is the product of prime numbers.

With that definition of “n-prime” numbers, 4 would be 3-prime and 8 would not (since it is divisible by 4). Then 8 is not a product of 3-prime numbers.

For cryptography, prime numbers are often used because $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a finite field. But that’s only true for “real” prime numbers, not for “n-prime” numbers that are not prime numbers.

By the way, I hate that definition of prime number that you quoted, because it gives the feeling that there’s something special with 2, while there is not.